# Logical indexing with list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, matrix-indexing

My code currently stands as follows:

```
z = np.diagflat(c).dot(D).dot(x);
idxN, idxP = z<0, z>=0 # logical indexing
y1 = [-1 + np.exp(x)/(1+np.exp(x)) for x in z[idxN]]
y1 = np.array(y1) # Size (504,)
y2 = [-np.exp(-x)/(1+np.exp(-x)) for x in z[idxP]]
y2 = np.array(y2) # Size (496,)
```

Now I'm trying to form a (1000,) list `y` which will incorporate y1 or y2 depending on whether the index is +/-.

I'm guessing a list comprehension would be the easiest but I'm struggling with the form. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: As I understood correctly, you have two logical arrays `idxN` and `idxP`, 1000 elements each?

Comment: @Colonder: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Easiest way should be to use the indices to set back the values***, *then flatten it back, if required*:

```
z_out = np.empty(z.shape, dtype='float')
z_out[idxN] = y1                           # values for negative indices
z_out[idxP] = y2                           # values for positive indices

z_out.flatten()                            # flatten it to 1D array, if required
```

***PS:*** When you subset a *ndarray* to create another *1D array*, you loose the indices information of the original *ndarray*. Therefore, for a *list comprehension* you might need to *enumerate* over both the newly created 1D arrays and the original *ndarray* simultaneously.

Comment: This actually worked. I was under the impression that 
z_out[idxN] = y1                           # values for negative indices
statements don't go down well with Python. I've tried something like this before and it didn't work.

Comment: yup that happens sometimes. you need to be be careful if you are creating a new array or overwriting over it and the dtypes involved. This was the reason I explicitly specify the `dtype` as `float` before assigning values for this case.